# Custom Views Bulk Operation using Batch API

Tags: 6, views

I am using `Views Bulk Operation` for updating custom value. I created a custom Operation using `hook_action_info`. How can I use `Batch API` with my custom action if I have to Operate on maximum nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to VBO settings (when editing the view, next to Style: Views Bulk Operations) and for your operation select the "Use Batch API" radio button under "To execute operations".

Comment: It showing `Access Denied` in `?q=batch&op=start&id=13` url If I select all the rows. Not for single row.

Comment: Oh sry Its VBO issue, I read in readme.txt.

Comment: Thnx buddy.. :D